# Flickering in cam video display, why?

Tags: c++, winapi, video, opencv, flicker

I get flickering in my cam video display, even though I (think I) turned off background erasure. Why?

[image]

Even the text display above the video presentation flickers.

Full code [at Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/alfps/ahodgepodgewinapiandopencvprogram).

Perhaps most relevant code, the gizmo that display the video:

```
class ImageDisplay:
    public gizmo::SubGizmo
{
typedef gizmo::SubGizmo Base;
private:
    winapi::graphics::ColorDib      dib_;

protected:
    void onPaint( raw::DcHandle const dc ) CPP_IS_OVERRIDE
    {
        dib_.renderOn( dc );
    }

    bool onWmEraseBkgnd( raw::DcHandle const dc )
    {
        CPP_DECLARE_UNUSED( dc );
        return true;        // Just say it's done, so it won't be done again.
    }

    void onWmPaint() CPP_IS_OVERRIDE
    {
        callOnPaint();
    }

    virtual raw::LResult dispatchWm(
        raw::UInt const     messageId,
        raw::WParam const   wParam,
        raw::LParam const   lParam
        )
    {
        CPP_DUMMY_USE_OF( wParam );  CPP_DUMMY_USE_OF( lParam );

        typedef ImageDisplay W;
        switch( messageId )
        {
        case WM_ERASEBKGND:
            return FORWARD_WM_TO( this, W::onWmEraseBkgnd, WM_ERASEBKGND, wParam, lParam );
        }

        return Base::dispatchWm( messageId, wParam, lParam );
    }

public:
    void setImage( cvapi::ImageRef const newImage )
    {
        dib_ = win_cv::dibFrom( newImage );
        setExtent( newImage.extent() );
    }

    ImageDisplay(
        Gizmo&                  parent,
        int const               x,
        int const               y,
        cvapi::ImageRef const&  pic
        )
        : Base( parent, x, y, pic.width(), pic.height() )
        , dib_( win_cv::dibFrom( pic ) )
    {}
};
```

The main code from the video producer thread:

```
void imageProducer( 
    wstring const&              namePattern,
    PutFunction const           putResult,
    Thread::Control const&      threadControl
    )
{
    assert( !!putResult );

    cv::VideoCapture cap( 0 );  // Open the default camera.
    hopefully( cap.isOpened() )
        || throwX( "cam::imageProducer: VideoCapture::<init> failed" );

    for(;;)
    {
        cv::Mat frame;

        if( threadControl.exitIsRequested() ) { return; }
        cap >> frame;           // Get a new frame from camera.

        if( threadControl.exitIsRequested() ) { return; }
        putResult( frame );
    }
}
```

The `putResult` function just calls Windows’s `SendMessage`, which synchronizes with the display thread.

I can't see how the flicker manages to sneak in?

---

**EDIT**: I found a fix, namely adding `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` to the main window, and using `RedrawWindow` to force immediate redrawing of the control (child window). Big mystery why it works. Bigger mystery: without `RedrawWindow` applied, `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` causes extreme slowness, like 1 frame every 20 secs?

**EDIT 2**: it didn't last. :-(

**EDIT 3**: *** S O L V E D ***. And *mea culpa*. All that flicker was caused by an inappropriate call to `InvalidateRect`, in the main window code. I had probably put it there just to test things, and forgotten to remove it. Argh!

Comment: Did you double buffer the output?

Comment: @DeadMG: I'm not sure that applies. As you can see above I just copy the image to a DIB, and then bitblast that DIB on WM_PAINT. Double buffering is where you write to one buffer while the display reads another, and then you switch those for the next cycle.

Comment: @Alf: Double buffering applies in any case where you want to be displaying smooth animated images.

Comment: @DeadMG: well, it is kinda double-buffered. but with WM_PAINT you copy to a device context. i think i would have to get down to vendor-specific graphics card to do real double buffering.

Comment: I suppose, it also matters if the form's double buffering is turned on.

Comment: @vines: thanks but this ain't a form, just plain ole' Windows API and a little C++ dressing on top

Comment: can you clarify what exactly you mean by flickering, I can think of a few things you could mean.

Comment: @thecoshman: it looks like a momentary whitening. I have verified that the main window receives a steady stream of WM_ERASEBCKNG, implying that its whole client area has been invalidated (presumably as a result of updating the picture presentation control). But even with WS_CLIPCHILDREN style, for each such the text presentation control received WM_PAINT.

Comment: So it is more like the window is filled with white (lol, I actually wrote shite first time around) and then the new content is drawn. Rather then the new content being drawn to a back buffer and then swapped; though I am fairly sure such a system does not work with normal win32 rendering.

Comment: @thecoshman:  Yes, except that now it works. I found the culprit, and it was a redundant and for final code downright stupid call to `InvalidateRect` on the main window. I probably put it there for testing something, and forgot to remove it...

Answer (score 2):

*Mea culpa*. All that flicker was caused by an inappropriate call to Windows’ `InvalidateRect`, in the main window code. I had probably put that call there just to test things, and forgotten to remove it. Argh!

Learning point:

Do not blame the “system” (here the Windows API, but also compiler etc.) before you have checked absolutely everything in your own code. It is like dirty fingerprints on your glasses. You never put your fingers on your glasses, and yet these fingerprints appear; same with mysterious undesirable statements in the code.